# Forward data from php script to calendar

Tags: php, ajax, push-notification

I have a project where I need to do the following: retrieve some data from a form, fill the database, create a response for the user and post the data to a third party. To give an example, it's like booking a ticket to a concert.The ajax call: You buy the ticket, you receive a response (whether the purchase was successful), a php script sends data to the database, and someone may be announced that a new ticket was bought. Now, I need to pass data to that "someone".  Which is what I don't know how to do.

Or, like when someone posts a comment to my question on stackoverflow, I get a notification.

In my particular case, the user creates an event, receives a response and I will need to have certain parameters posted by the user on a calendar. It is important that I could hardly integrate the calendar with the script retrieving the data. I would rather need to "forward" the data to the calendar- quite like pushing notifications.
Can anyone please give me a clue what should I use, or what should I need in order to do the above?

The process will go like this:

```
    AJAX   
user----> php script->database
                 |_ calendar
```

Comment: So you want to post ("push") the data in php to the calendar after you added the info to the database?

Comment: After adding it to the database you can render your calendar with the new data and set the output html in your javascript function to the right html element when the ajax post was succesful.

Comment: @TobiasKun yes. The data may be filtered, but since I don't know how to render when the database is updated, I thought it should be on one hand to add info to database, and on the other hand to post the data to the calendar

Comment: @randomizer I have thought about it, but I can honestly say the only thing that passes through my mind is to retrieve information from time to time. How should I render it when the database is updated?

Comment: After the database update you could output a json object which contains your calendar which you are building with your database data.
$response = array('calender'=>'<div>calendar</div>'); and in your javascript you can say overwrite the html code of the current calendar with the passed code from my php response.

Comment: @randomizer ok, but again, how will my calendar know the database was updated? How will it receive the response?

Comment: As I said, if you perform an ajax call after adding data, this page handles the adding of the data to the database and responses with a json object.
In your javascript code, you will receive this response and you can handle it by setting the new html source of your calendar to the received response.

Comment: @randomizer The form is filled by one user, while the calendar is seen by another user.
The json will indeed be sent back, but the calendar is at another user. How do I send the json there?

Comment: For example, you fill in the form, and I have the calendar. I need the calendar updated when you finished filling the form.

Comment: Ok, then you are going to do something like ajax polling to refresh the calendar frequently to show updates.

Answer (score 1):

So if i get you right, you could post your data to the calendar via curl:

```
$url = "http://www.your-url-to-the-calendar.com";
$postData = array(
    "prop1" => "value1",
    "prop2" => "value2",
    "prop3" => "value3"
);
//urlify the data for the post
$data_string = "";
foreach ($postData as $key => $value)
    $data_string .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
$data_string = rtrim($data_string, '&');
//will output --> prop1=value1&prop2=value2=prop3=value3

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => count($postData),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

If your third party calendar does not require authentication than this would be the best way to post it, if you can not write to the database yourself.
When it requires authentication you would have to first login via curl (send credentials via curl-post, receive cookies, send cookies with your data)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only problem might be if I would have some large parameters: for example a huge description of the event I would need to pass- that case might lead to a url that would exceed the allowed limit

Comment: But the value you should check is your post_max_size. Because you post it, not add it to your url as a GET param.

Comment: My comment in the code ("urlify") could be a bit confusing though. Keep me updated if this helped :)

Comment: Will curl_exec also redirect me to the calendar? (That would result in another redirect to the main page, because the user who fills the form has no access to the calendar

Comment: No it won't. `$result` will hold the server answer. This could be the success-message or it tries to redirect you to a login form. Depends on the calendar itself. But unless you do not output the result it won't do anything.

Comment: Okay. I tried it, works.. somehow.
But, supposing I am on one computer, completing the form and you are on another, with the calendar, after I complete the form, you would need to have a new entry in the calendar.

Any idea how can I actually do that.

The above answer applies if I go form->above php script-> calendar on my own machine

Comment: You could update your calendar via ajax every 5 minutes or so, so the changes i made on my machine will be visible to you in at maximum of 5 minutes. Or you wait until i refresh my calendar page. It's up to you.